# Why does GetName in System.Reflection.Assembly appear to throw a NotImplementedException when decompiled?

Tags: c#, reflection, mscorlib

While debugging an issue I was digging in to mscorlib and specifically at `GetName()` in `System.Reflection.Assembly`.

Looking at the code for the method in dotPeek and also on [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/assembly.cs,1fd23b897ffa9a75,references) the code for `GetName()` seems to have nothing in it and throws a `NotImplementedException`:

```
#if FEATURE_CORECLR
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical] // auto-generated
#endif
    public virtual AssemblyName GetName()
    {
        return GetName(false);
    }

#if FEATURE_CORECLR
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical] // auto-generated
#endif
    public virtual AssemblyName GetName(bool copiedName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Can anyone explain why this appears to throw an exception, but using a line of code such as `typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()` returns the correct version of the DLL?

Comment: Note that there are types *derived* from `Assembly` - notably [`RuntimeAssembly`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/assembly.cs,73b5be5e9c2474b2,references).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `Assembly` is a base class, the actual object you get back at runtime (in this particular setting) is a `RuntimeAssembly` which *does* implement that method.

Depending on how you obtain the `Assembly` object, there are different actual types at play, be it for actual runtime code or reflection-only spelunking or whatnot.

But `Assembly` is a base class.

I can say this unequivocally because the `Assembly` class is abstract, as evident from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/assembly.cs,59):

```
public abstract class Assembly : _Assembly, IEvidenceFactory, ICustomAttributeProvider, ISerializable
```

And it's also [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly?view=netframework-4.7):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterface(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
public abstract class Assembly : System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider, System.Runtime.InteropServices._Assembly, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable, System.Security.IEvidenceFactory
```

Therefore, any instance of an object that fits an `Assembly` variable has to be a derived class.

Comment: Assembly is an `abstract` class and therefore _always_ a base class.